# Set the Column Value when show the NewListForm.aspx using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()

Tags: list, javascript, modal-dialog

i want to set the selected SPList Title value when show the NewListForm.aspx using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(), could anyone help me to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

In showModalDialog you can pass [arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28office.14%29.aspx) that get passed on to the dialog.

If you would pass the title as an argument, then modify the NewListForm.aspx slightly using SharePoint Designer to add javascript functionality that would take that argument and put it in the Title field.

Comment: Hello Jussi Palo, i am not asking about the popup window title, i have one list, this name is List1 and List1 has 5 columns like Title, Date, Currency, Created, Modified, i want to set Test as Title for List1 when show the NewForm.aspx using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(), could you help me please

Comment: Yes, I'm also talking about the title field of the item you're showing in the dialog - not the title of the dialog. You would populate the Title textbox with the value that you pass as the argument.